# Señal cuando item es movido internamente en un QListWidget de PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

Tengo un `QListWidget` con varios items y quiero obtener una lista con los items en el mismo orden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
lista = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
```

Hasta aquí bien.

Si ahora cambio el orden de los items en el `QListWidget` con el ratón, quiero que la lista se actualice con el nuevo orden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
lista = ['Item 1', 'Item 3', 'Item 2']
```

No encuentro ninguna [señal](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#currentItemChanged) para esto. ¿Qué solución debo tomar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres ser notificado cada vez que se cambia el orden de los items puedes usar la señal [rowsMoved()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsMoved) del modelo que maneja QListWidget. En la siguiente parte muestro un ejemplo:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=None)

        self.list_widget = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.list_widget.addItems(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'])
        self.setCentralWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.list_widget.model().rowsMoved.connect(self.onRowsMoved)

    def onRowsMoved(self, *args):
        for i in range(self.list_widget.count()):
            it = self.list_widget.item(i)
            print(it.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```